# How to draw a route by tracking my current locations in android using Google maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I got my current locations latitude and longitude. But I don't know how to continuously get my current location values.

I know I have to use onLocationChanged method to get the updates. But I want to update it every second while I am moving. Can anyone please help me..??

Comment: try this http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822

Comment: thank you Anjali. But I already drawn a route from source to destination. I used the same code you have suggested. Now I want to get periodical updates of my current location. And have to draw a route on my own with that values.

Comment: you can use same code for that the difference is to change the source address..

Comment: use this..https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See requestLocationUpdates(long, float, Criteria, PendingIntent) for more detail on how to use this method.

Parameters

1. **provider** the name of the provider with which to register
2. **minTime**  minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds
3. **minDistance**  minimum distance between location updates, in meters
4. **listener** a LocationListener whose onLocationChanged(Location) method will be called for each location update

In your case put minTime to 1000 (1 sec)